# Create Instance in aws using boto3 Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create an instance in aws using boto3.

```
instance = ec2.create_instances(
ImageId='ami-15e9c770',
MinCount=1,
MaxCount=1,
InstanceType='t2.micro',
KeyName="xyz",
Placement={'AvailabilityZone':'us-east-2b'})
```

I am using this code which creates an instance but it does not let me connect to the instance.Am i wrong somewhere.What other things do i need to do to ssh to the instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not let me connect to the instance"? How are you trying to connect, and what happens? Have you associated a Security Group with the instance? If not, you need to do so, permitting the appropriate connection (eg Port 22 = SSH).

Comment: Since you didn't specify the VPC id, subnet id, security group,  the api simply put everything under a default VPC, subnet. security group. You should check out the default setting on the connection part.

Answer (score 0):

use this script to make connection to your instance

```
import boto3
import botocore
import paramiko

key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(path/to/mykey.pem)
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect/ssh to an instance
try:
    # Here 'ubuntu' is user name and 'instance_ip' is public IP of EC2
    client.connect(hostname=instance_ip, username="ubuntu", pkey=key)

    # Execute a command(cmd) after connecting/ssh to an instance
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
    print stdout.read()

    # close the client connection once the job is done
    client.close()
    break

except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Comment: But its the same as that of this command:  ssh -i key.pem user@ip. This does not work it gives connection timed out

Comment: troubleshoot your instance ssh    

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/

and try again

Comment: Thanks Mausam Actually I got a solution to this question.You also have to add the Security group parameter there in my code only then you can connect to the instance.